# Pulse audio error and strange noise when using VLC on Wheezy

Tags: linux, audio, vlc-media-player, pulse-audio, raspberry-pi

I am trying to play audio files on my Raspberry pi using VLC, but I am getting a "Pulse audio output error" and the song has a huge amount of random noise.

Here is a little video that shows what I am trying to do - sorry the quality is not so good, I took the video with my phone :/

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VqfNHPvg1tU&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Please don't post videos like that, the messages are incomprehensible and I don't want to have to follow a link to youtube to understand what you are doing. Either copy the messages into your post or include a screenshot (take it with your phone if you must).

Comment: The actual audio of the video is the important part.  If there is a better way for me to post the audio I am open to it.

Comment: Fair enough about the audio, but the important thing is the commands you are running and the specific error messages received and I cannot really read them on your screen.